# How to use Advanced image pickers, display Image in Src tag and upload in Cordova Android, year 2023

Tags: android, cordova, uri

I was having an issue fetching an image to display using the Cordova Advanced Image picker, so i am just writing down my research and how i managed to resolve that.

Cordova Android
Cordova version 11
Cordova android version 11
How to use an image selector, to select an image, then display an image, and upload that image.
The image display breaks if just placing a path return from the Cordova Advanced Imagepicker, and also wont upload with that URI returned.

Clark

Answer (score 0):

The situation:
1.) How to pick an image, then display it, then upload that image.
2.) Cordova 11, Cordova Android 11
3.) I use the cordova plugin advanced imagepicker
4.) It returns an URI like this content://media/external/images/media/681 (https://github.com/EinfachHans/cordova-plugin-advanced-imagepicker/issues/25)
5.) Then have to use the cordova-plugin-filepath (but its deprecated)
5b.) It will return an absolute file URI path that you can use in XMLHTTPS request for upload
6.) Then you can use the cordova file plugin function and it will return an URL, that you can put into src for display
resolveLocalFileSystemURL(testurl, function(entry) {
console.log('cdvfile URI: ' + entry.toInternalURL());})

Hope it helps anyone that is looking for this info.
Clark